# Is is possible to refer to Type Variables in pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, type-variables

The following code (which is not meant to do anything useful) compiles fine :

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import System.Random

uselessFunction :: (RandomGen g) => g -> [Int]
uselessFunction gen = 
  let (value::Int, newGen) = (random gen)
  in (uselessFunction newGen)
```

Is it possible for me to use type variables in the pattern matching, in the following spirit (code fails to compile):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import System.Random

uselessFunction :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [a]
uselessFunction gen = 
  let (value::a, newGen) = (random gen)
  in (uselessFunction newGen)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've already noticed that the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension allows you to put type annotations on patterns.  But for the extension's *main* purpose, to make a type variable be locally scoped so that you can refer to it inside the function, you must also declare it with a forall in the type declaration, like so:

```
uselessFunction :: forall a g. (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [a]
```

This doesn't change the meaning of the declaration itself, but hints to GHC that you may want to use the variable locally.

Comment: In particular, I think the `forall` is just needed for backwards compatibility, so that turning the extension on doesn't accidentally break previously valid code.

Answer (score 0):

The real way out of this is described in [*Type Variables in Patterns*, by Richard A. Eisenberg, Joachim Breitner, Simon Peyton Jones](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03476):

> For many years, GHC has implemented an extension to Haskell that
>   allows type variables to be bound in type signatures and patterns, and
>   to scope over terms. This extension was never properly specified. We
>   rectify that oversight here. With the formal specification in hand,
>   the otherwise-labyrinthine path toward a design for binding type
>   variables in patterns becomes blindingly clear. We thus extend
>   ScopedTypeVariables to bind type variables explicitly, obviating the
>   Proxy workaround to the dustbin of history.